# Is there a way to use multiple aws profiles to deploy(update) serverless stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

We have a team of 3 to 4 members so we wanted to do serverless deploy or update functions or resources using our own personnel AWS credentials without creating new stack but just updating the existing resources. Is there a way to do that? I am aware that we can set up --aws-profile  and different profiles for different stages. I am also aware that we cloud just divide the resources into microservices and just deploy or update our own parts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow!
what do you mean by "without creating new stack"? please update you answer with proper description and the way you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as below:

- Add the `profile` configuration as below, i ha e named it as `devProfile`.

```
service: new-service
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  profile: devProfile
```

Each individual would set their credentials under their own machine as below:

```
aws configure --profile devProfile
```

If you have different credentials for different `stage`, then above serverless snippet can be implemented in parameterized way as below:

serverless.yml

```
custom:
  stages:
    - local
    - dev
    - prod
  # default stage/environment
  defaultStage: local
  # default AWS region
  defaultRegion: us-east-1
  # config file / region / stage
  configFile: ${file(./config/${opt:region,self:provider.region}/${self:provider.stage}.yml)}


Provider:
  ...
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.defaultStage}
  ...
  profile: ${self:custom.configFile.aws.profile}
  ...
```

Create `config/us-east-1/dev.yml`

```
aws:
  profile: devProfile
```

and `config/us-east-1/prod.yml`

```
aws:
  profile: prodProfile
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful briefing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know what to do but need a sanity check. So I'll tell you how I, and everyone else I know, handles this.

We prefix commands with `AWS_PROFILE` env var declared and we use `--stage` names.

E.g. `AWS_PROFILE=mycompany sls deploy --stage shailendra`.

Google `aws configure` for examples on how to set up `awscli` that uses the `AWS_PROFILE` var.

We also name the `--stage` with a unique ID, e.g. your name. This way, you and your colleagues all have individual CloudFormation stacks that work independently of eachother and there will be no conflicts.

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot.